# Suddenly getting 403 (Forbidden) with Oauth 2.0 consent on YouTube V3 API

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth

I have 3 youtube brand accounts with channels.
To two of them I'm connected and successfully authenticated, but the third one gives me a 403 error when I try to authenticate.

I use the python youtube upload script.
I have set up the credentials and projects, enabled YouTube v3 api and everything.
I did it couple of hours ago for the 2nd account and now the 3rd one is not working.

What could be the issue?

1. Choose your account or a brand account
   to continue to youtubeupload:

   - I choose a brand account I manage (but I do not own it, only manage).
2. Error 403. That’s an error. We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page

Comment: What's the URL of the page serving the 403?

Comment: @Nick it's a standard google auth consent url response. You can reproduce this error if you do this: 1. Become a manager for someone else's youtube. 2. Go to https://myaccount.google.com of the brand account you become manager of. 3. The Error 403 Forbidden appears

Comment: Does the error occur for brand accounts you own, or just ones you manage? myaccount.google.com doesn't trigger an OAuth flow, which is different from what you have as Step 1 in your original post.

Comment: @Nick it only happens to accounts I manage (different owner). I try to authenticate with Youtube API and I need oauth consent, so I pick MY account and then a Youtube channel I manage (only as manager). Then it redirects me to 403 error.

Comment: I am getting this too - with the account set the 'Manage', I am unable to log in via the API. Changing to 'Owner' seems to be the only way to get past it at the moment

Comment: @Joe the problem is that I'm not the owner. I got picked as a manager, yet Google doesn't let me manage.

Comment: @VixinG it seems to be a bug introduced very recently - this worked up until a couple of weeks ago

Comment: @VixinG I'm getting this too, any updates?

Comment: No, still bugged. On top of that there is now a bug that prevents me from uploading to youtube from drive/photos. It's stuck on "processing upload".

Comment: We are also seeing this error. We're using the read only analytics access scope when authenticating. If we own the channel we can get through. If we are only managers we get the 403 "That's an error, We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know." message.

We're seeing this in both the PHP SDK, on custom CURL scripts and in Laravel's Socialite Youtube module as we've tried to figure out if the error is originating in the code. No matter which way we auth we get the same 403 message.

Comment: Are 403s appearing during the OAuth consent flow or after completing it? What's the path of the page serving the 403?

Comment: @Nick 403 happened as soon as you chose the brand account and confirmed your selection (after first picking the main google account), on the first OAuth pre-redirect link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue should be resolved now. As part of rolling out the new signin [experience](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7338427) a bug was introduced that caused the issue. We have rolled back to the previous behavior while we fix the root cause.

Comment: Man, thank you so much. You don't even know how much I went through to workaround this. I had to use Google Photos import to YouTube (which is now also broken, I hope you know that).

Comment: Just want to let you know we're trying to rollout the new signin experience again. We believe the original issue is fixed. Please ping this thread if you experience any more issues related to OAuth for brand accounts.